# Error Receiving State Data from Child Component

Tags: reactjs

I'm running into an error with handling a returned POST value between a parent and child component. I believe it is because I am not setting the initial object to the empty `comments` array, but I'm not sure why an `undefined` is getting thrown if the `comments` property is set within the state.

**Error Message:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'comments' of undefined
    at Object.updateCommentsFunc [as updateComments]
```

**Parent Component (Fetch Object):**

```
//GET /app and set to state
class PictureFeedContainer extends React.Component{
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = this.context.data || window.__INITIAL_STATE__ || {pictures: []};
    }

    fetchList() {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/app')
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })  
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                this.setState({ pictures: data.picture, user: data.user, csrf: data.csrfToken });
            }) 
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchList();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h2>Comments List</h2>
                <PictureFeed {...this.state} />
            </div>
        )
    }
};
```

**Parent Component (Passing Object to Child Component):**

```
class PictureFeed extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            comments: []
        };
    }

    updateCommentsFunc(newComments){
        console.log("Update Comments Func Triggered");
        //console.log(typeof this.state.comments);
        //console.log(this.state.comments);
        this.setState({comments: [...this.state.comments, newComments]});
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
            { 
                this.props.pictures.map((picture, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 picture-card">
                                <PictureCard {...picture} key={picture.pictureIdHash} user={this.props.user} />
                                <Comments {...picture} key={index} pictureId={picture.pictureIdHash} csrf={this.props.csrf} updateComments={this.updateCommentsFunc}/> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
                })
            }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Child Component (Receiving Object):**

```
export default class Comments extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="picture-comment-container">
                <CommentForm updateComments={this.props.updateComments} pictureId={this.props.pictureId} csrf={this.props.csrf}/>
                { this.props.picture_comments.map((comment, i) => 
                    <Comment {...comment} key={this.props.pictureCommentId}/>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Child Component (Form and parent function call):**

```
class CommentForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: ''
        };

        this.postComment = this.postComment.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    postComment(comment, pictureId, csrfToken) {
        console.log(comment);
        console.log(pictureId);
        console.log(csrfToken);
        var body = { comment: comment };
        var route = 'http://localhost:3000/app/picture/' + pictureId + '/comment';
        fetch(route, 
            { 
                method: 'POST', 
                body: JSON.stringify(body), 
                headers: { 
                    'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken,
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })  
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                this.props.updateComments(data);
            }) 
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }

    onChange(e){
        this.setState({
            value: e.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.postComment(this.state.value, this.props.pictureId, this.props.csrf);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="picture-comment__form">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <label>Comment:</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                        <form action={"/app/picture/" + this.props.pictureId + "/comment"} method="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value={this.props.csrf}/>
                            <div className="col-md-9">
                                <textarea name="comment" className="picture-comment__form-text-area" onChange={e => this.setState({ value: e.target.value })} value={this.state.value}></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-3">
                                <button type="submit" className="picture-comment__form-button" disabled={!this.state.value}>Comment</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, you're not supposed to "get" state data from child component. Either you need to add stuff to your parent component and pass as a prop, or you should be using redux, yes, you can however do dirty tricks to make this work, but that's agains react. Please look into redux once :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. In an effort to avoid Redux at the moment, could I set the `comments` array in the parent component with the initial data by passing the looped `picture_coments` on `componentDidMount()` and then change the `setState` in the `updateCommentsFunc()` to append the function parameter to the `comments` array?